# Using Linux int 80h system calls under Cygwin?

Tags: c, assembly, makefile, cygwin, nasm

I am using **Cygwin 32-bit** under Win7 in a 64-bit machine.

The following program

### makefile

```
runme:  main.cpp    asm.o
    g++     main.cpp    asm.o   -o  executable

asm.o:  asm.asm
    nasm    -f   elf    asm.asm     -o  asm.o
```

### asm.asm

```
    section .data
    hello:     db 'Hello world!',10
    helloLen:  equ $-hello
section .bss
section .text
    global _GetValueFromASM, _HelloWorld

_GetValueFromASM:
    mov eax, 9
    ret

_HelloWorld:
    mov eax,4            ; 'write' system call = 4
    mov ebx,1            ; file descriptor 1 = STDOUT
    mov ecx,hello        ; string to write
    mov edx,helloLen     ; length of string to write
    int 80h              ; call the kernel
    ret
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int GetValueFromASM();
extern "C" int HelloWorld();

int main()
{
    HelloWorld();
    cout<<"GetValueFromASM() returned = "<<GetValueFromASM()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

is giving me the following error:

```
me@my-PC ~/nasm/test of Intel syntax
$ make
nasm    -f      elf             asm.asm         -o      asm.o
g++       main.cpp        asm.o   -o      executable

me@my-PC ~/nasm/test of Intel syntax
$ ./executable
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am not understanding why this error is being generated.

How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: Did you try debugging it at all?

Comment: `int 80h` will not work under cygwin. It only emulates the posix functions via a library, not the syscall interface.